# Do the PowerShell cmdlets Set-ADComputer and Get-ADComputer work outside of OU=COMPUTER?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, cifs

I would like to know if `Set-ADComputer` and `Get-ADComputer` work only for objects presents inside the `OU=Computer` or if these cmdlets are compatible with any other location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cmdlets work in the whole AD!
You may specify single computer, by using parameter `-identity`:

> The Identity parameter specifies the Active Directory computer to
>   modify. You can identify a computer by its distinguished name, GUID,
>   security identifier (SID) or Security Accounts Manager (SAM) account
>   name. You can also set the Identity parameter to an object variable
>   such as $, or you can pass an object through the
>   pipeline to the Identity parameter. For example, you can use the
>   Get-ADComputer cmdlet to retrieve a computer object and then pass the
>   object through the pipeline to Set-ADComputer.

or you may use parameter `-filter` to filter based on a specific criteria, throughout the whole AD, or specify a OU with parameter `-SearchBase`.

More details at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adcomputer?view=win10-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps